# About circles and MVT

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

We know that the MVT proves the existence of some "c" inside the range $(a, b)$ such that $\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}=f'(c)$ for some well defined function f.

We also know that the function $y=\sqrt{r^2-x^2}$ is a circle with radius $r$ drewn in the first quadrant. So it came to my attention, what is the particular c for any given $a, b (0<a<b<r)$ that satisfies the MVT for a circle? I know that c can be expressed cleanly in functions of a and b for some functions, for example quadratic functions have $c=\frac{a+b}{2}$.

I done some thinking, and as $L_{(c, f(c))}$ is the angle bisector of $L_{(a, f(a))}$ and $L_{(b, f(b))}$, (where $L_{(p, q)}$ indicates the line between the circle's center and the point (p, q)), so we can do some trigonometry.

Let $\alpha$ be the angle between $L_{(a, f(a))}$ and the x-axis, $\beta$ be the angle between $L_{(b, f(b))}$ and the x-axis. Then the angle between $L_{(c, f(c))}$ and the x-axis is $\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}$.
Then, by some simple trigonometry,
$$c=r\cos(\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2})=r\sqrt{\frac{\cos(\alpha+\beta)+1}{2}}=r\sqrt{\frac{\cos\alpha\cos\beta-\sin\alpha\sin\beta+1}{2}}=r\sqrt{\frac{\frac{a}{r}\frac{b}{r}-\frac{\sqrt{r^2-a^2}}{r}\frac{\sqrt{r^2-b^2}}{r}+1}{2}}
=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sqrt{ab-\sqrt{(r^2-a^2)(r^2-b^2)}+r^2}$$

So, after all of this, **my final question is**, 1. Am I right? 2. Given only the fact that $c$ is given like this above, can we track down $f$?

Comment: @Chrystomath Oh silly of me, sorry! I'll edit it.

Comment: It's a hard question to answer. It leads to differential equations of the sort $y'(c(x))=F(y(x),x)$, which are more general than standard odes. Would be interesting to see an answer.